# Issue with drop down selection in JSF2.0 Mojarra

Tags: jsf-2

I'm having a drop down (list of `SelectItem`s) in which first item is with a `label`=`'Please select'` and `value`=`null`. Having this, validation (`required=true`) is working fine when I try to submit the page with out selecting any value from the drop down. Also, on value change I'm making an AJAX call which basically will refresh another component. My backing bean is in `SessionScope`.

Now problem is, from the point AJAX call happened, when ever I try to select `Please select`  from the drop down, it is not allowing me do that and setting drop down value automatically to the value which I selected just before AJAX call. Can any one suggest where the possible issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Just set `immediate="true"` attribute in your `f:ajax` tab. This will process your event in **Apply Request Values phase**, before **Validation phase**.